# "is necessary" vs "it is necessary"

Tags: grammaticality, differences

Which one is correct:

> To perform a task **is necessary** to do some things.

or

> To perform a task **it is necessary** to do some things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need **it**:

> To perform a task, *it* is necessary
>   to do some things.

The reason is that, in your sentence without *it*, the subject *to do some things* would come after the finite verb *is*: because it is generally not possible to have no subject before the verb, you need a dummy subject *it* to come before the verb, at least in non-inverted word order.

I think most people would add the comma here, though I'd not consider it absolutely necessary.

You even need *it* when used in a relative clause, according to style books:

> The Hanseatic League, which *it* is
>   necessary to have on our side, still
>   refuses to boycott Spanish traders.

The reason is that you couldn't replace *it* with the subject of the subordinate clause. *Which* refers to *the Hanseatic League* (the *antecedent*), and we should then be able to replace *which* with its antecedent:

> ? The Hanseatic League is necessary to
>   have on our side ...

But this sounds slightly off or different. It is not *the Hanseatic League* that is necessary in order to *have x on our side*: it is *having the H. L. on our side* as a whole that is necessary for some unmentioned purpose. (If this were possible, it would be a case of *[raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29)*, as with *it seems she has left us* => *she seems to have left us*, where there is no difference in meaning.) We'd still need a dummy subject here:

> It is necessary to have the Hanseatic
>   League on our side ...

Note that it would sound more natural to say *we need the H. L. on our side*.

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct but they have different meanings.  In addition, I would not use the first example.

Suppose that you have to click a button when you want to print out a document (in a computer program).  Then I *could* say:

1. To print out a document, it is necessary to click a button.
2. Clicking a button is necessary to print out a document.
3. To click a button is necessary to print out a document.

Note the difference in the order.

I prefer to use a comma in 1, but some people omit it.

I would not use 3 because it is hard to understand for me.  This is because when I see “To click a button” at the beginning of the sentence, I expect a sentence like the first one and therefore expect to see a subject later, but actually “To click a button” is the subject.  However, I would not say 3 is incorrect.

Comment: I do not understand the silent downvoting here.  Some people seem to assume that “to perform a task” is a goal and “to do some things” is a means, but if it is the opposite, the first example in the question is correct (although it is hard to understand).  And from the vague example in the question, I cannot tell which is a goal and which is a means.

Comment: I would not use 3 either and so, without a good reason, I suspect it may not be correct

Comment: I agree that 3 is bad style at best: two constituents with *to*-infinitives is hard to parse.

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree that 3 is bad style.  As Colin Fine writes in a comment on JSBangs’s answer, it is a garden-path sentence (I had been forgetting this phrase when I wrote this answer), at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the second one, but it's a bit unclear (in written form). Insert a *comma*:

> To perform a task, it is necessary to do some things.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is correct:

> To perform a task it is necessary to do some things.

The reason for this is that the verb *is* needs a subject. Verbs in English always have to have an explicit subject, with a handful of exceptions (the imperative being the most common). Therefore, whenever we have a statement with no logical subject, we have to add the word *it* (or sometimes *there*) in order to act as a placeholder subject. For example:

> *It* is raining.

The words *it* doesn't refer to anything in particular here, but it's required by the grammar of English to supply a subject.

In your sentence, you might be tempted to analyze the infinitive *to perform a task* as the subject. This is incorrect, however. The infinitive here is actually an adjunct, with an understood prepositional *in order* preceding it. You can demonstrate this by moving the infinitive to the end of the sentence:

> It is necessary to do some things in order to perform a task.

Here's it's clear that *to perform a task* is an adjunct, and that the verb *is* requires the dummy subject *it*. The same thing applies, though somewhat less obviously, when the infinitive is moved to the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: As Tsuyoshi Ito says, the reading with "to perform a task" is grammatical, but has a different meaning. This makes it something of a garden-path sentence, so it is unlikely to occur, but it could.